# Bash function calling another function that requires passing user-defined options

Tags: bash, function

I have a function `plist` that is able to call `head` and `tail` commands.  But for processing regions I call a different function `pregion`.

```
# --- plist ---

  ("-H"|"--head")
    local -r hn="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
  ("-T"|"--tail")
    local -r tm="$2" ; shift 2 ;;

  ("--FS")                           # field separator
    local fs="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
  ("--incl")
    local incl+=("$2") ; shift 2 ;;  # file type suffix
  ("--excl")
    local excl+=("$2") ; shift 2 ;;  # file type suffix

  ("--RP")
    local pn=$2 ; shift 2 ;;
  ("--RQ")
    local qn=$2 ; shift 2 ;;

  ("--dyn"|"--dynamic")
    local dyn="1" ; shift 1 ;;
  ("-C"|"--context")
    local ctx=$2 ; shift 2 ;;

  ("-d"|"--directory")
    local fdir=$2 ; shift 2 ;;

  (--)
    shift;  break  ;;

  ...

  if [[ -v hn ]]; then

     head -v -hn "$n"
    
  elif [[ -v tm ]]; then

    tail -v -n "$tm"

  elif [[ -v dyn ]]; then

    pregion "$@"  # requires original options here

  fi
```

With `head` and `tail`, I only use options `-H`, `-T`', `--FS`,
and `--incl`.  Because I am using `shift` when processing options, I need to have a copy ef the original `plist` input arguments, because I cannot simply pass `"$@"` to `pregion`.

This will call `head` or `tail`

```
  plist -H 8 ./01cuneus

  plist -T 13 ./01cuneus
```

Examples of calling `pregion`

```
plist --dyn -C 8 "Martin" ./01cuneus

plist --incl .texi --incl .org --RP 8 --RQ 13 ./01cuneus

plist --incl .texi --incl .org --dyn -C 8 "Martin" ./01cuneus
```

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. There's no `shift` in this code. I don't see `-H`, `-T` etc. Why do you think you can't pass the args to pregion? You can make a copy of the incoming params to plist (`args=("$@")`) and use that to pass to pregion (`pregion "${args[@]}"`)

Comment: Can you modify that into a complete script showing this particular issue with the arguments? Include the interesting stuff about arguments, the way you process them, including the `shift`. What the problem is in passing `"$@"` as arg to `pregion`. Everything related to this issue. And rip out the parts that are irrelevant to this, if running `head` is not where the problem is, just remove it or replace with an `echo "this is where we'd call head / do this or that"` or so.

Comment: @glenn I did not include the options part, because passing arguments and setting variables in functions is customarily straighforward.  This simply focuses on passing the original options list intact because I call shift whilst processing tho arguments for `head` and `tail` in function `plist`.

Comment: (also how you're meaning the function should work, i.e. if called as `plist foo bar`, then do _this_, but if called with `plist -x -y abcd`, then do _this_.)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Pietru, while we might know how `getopts`, `"$@"`, functions and `shift` work, generally, we have no idea about your particular issue or goal. Not even if you've written questions on the same project before, because we might not have seen them, and at least don't know about the whole so can't connect the dots.

Comment: @Pietru, _"This simply focuses on passing the original options list intact"_ then show code that does that. And tell what it should do but what you get instead.

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Would it be enough to use `args=("$@")`, then call `pregion "$args"`.  Or would I need to take care of additional things?

Comment: Just use `pregion --dyn -C 8 "Martin" ./01cuneus`, etc. if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the orginal args to an array, and use that with `pregion`.  e.g.

```
plist() {
  local -a origargs=("$@")
  ...
  case
    ...
  esac
  ...

  if
    ...
  elif [[ -v dyn ]]; then
    pregion "${origargs[@]}"
  fi
```

Comment: Have figured out that the problem was being produced by an incorrect call using `pregion "$origargs"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed save the contents of `$@` to an array

```
plist() {
    local args
    args=("$@")
    case $1 in ...
        # some shifting etc.
    esac
    if something; then
        pregion "${args[@]}"
    fi
}
```

But, that would mean that `pregion` would need to do the whole option processing again. In effect, you'd implement the same process in two places. And what about returning errors for invalid options from `plist`? You couldn't do that before figuring out if you're going to call `pregion`, since it might accept some options `plist` doesn't.

Instead, I'd suggest doing the option parsing only once, and then calling `pregion` with the appropriate values already parsed to individual arguments:

```
plist() {
    local args
    args=("$@")
    local this=default that=otherdefault
    local call_pregion=
    case $1 in ...
        this) this=$2; shift; shift;;
        that) that=$2; shift; shift;;
        dyn) call_pregion=1
    esac
    if [ "$call_pregion" ]; then
        pregion "$this" "$that"
    fi
}
```

that way `pregion` can just take the values from static positions in the list, e.g. `$1` for `$this` and `$2` for `$that`.

Also, btw, using `shift 2` there is risky. Depending on the shell it may silently fail there aren't enough arguments to shift. E.g. `set a b c; shift 4; echo $1` will exit with an error in Dash, but in Bash, it'll happily just print `a`. That may leave your option parsing stuck in a loop if the user gives an option without the corresponding option-argument.

Comment: I fail to see how your comment on `shift 2`  can be resolved with `shift ; shift ;;`. when there aren't enough arguments to `shift`.

Comment: @Pietru, if you're looping until all the arguments are gone, you'll want to remove the ones you've processed. With just one arg, `shift 2` _leaves it there_. E.g. you're looking at `-H`, then `shift 2` does nothing, and the next time you're looking at the same `-H` again. In `shift; shift`, they work individually, and the first removes the first arg, regardless of if the second will fail since there is no other arg. Try e.g. `foo() { while [ "$1" ]; do case $1 in (-x) x=$2; shift 2;; esac; done; echo "x: $x"; }` vs. the same with `shift; shift` instead. Run with `foo -x test` and `foo -x`.

Comment: Does `shift` fail when it encounters `-this` or `--that` ?

Comment: Have done `local rp=$2 ; shift ; shift` followed by  `echo "\$@: $@" ;;`.  Running `plist --dyn --RP --RQ 8 "John" ./01cuneus` gave `$@: -- 8 John ./01cuneus`.  With `plist --dyn --RP 5 --RQ 8 "John" ./01cuneus`, I got  `$@: --RQ 8 -- Behistun ./01cuneus`. Seems to imply that calling `shift ; shift` behaves as `shift 2`.

Comment: @Pietru, try it without giving an argument to `--RP` or `--RQ`. Something like just `plist --dyn --RP 5 --RQ`.